# Extracting data from NSArray and NSArray.count

Tags: uitableview, nsarray, swift2

There are two questions to this post. I've a project that fetches JSON data, and stores in NSArray. The data will be extracted and display on UITableView.

This is the screenshot of my data during debug, and I've verified that I've successfully fetch the data.

[image]

I've 2 questions to this post.

1. Why when I do `var count = resultJSON.count`, the value is 0?
2. Because of the 1st part, I've failed to display the data of resultJSON on my table. So in order to "cheat" I return 9 to see if the data does display. However I can't display out to my table.

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        //let count = resultJSON.count
        return 9
    }`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = stockTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    for jsonObjectString in self.resultJSON{
        myCell.textLabel?.text = jsonObjectString["name"] as! String
        myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = jsonObjectString["company"]! as! String
    }

    return myCell
}`
```

Comment: `resultJSON`, `resultArray`?  Which is it?

Comment: Oops! resultJSON. However, even with return 9 to cheat, my second part of the question doesn't work.

Comment: Well that doesn't inspire confidence in the accuracy of your question.

Comment: You're looping over your array, overriding the same cell over and over. UITableViews don't work like that. You should study some tutorials. This one looks ok: https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: Even so, it should display the last looped value right?

Comment: Put breakpoints on your return statements to verify that they're being called.  If they are not, check how you set your table's data source.

Comment: Yes it's called. But value is 0. In addition, why does my debug goes into the thread, and I can't view the actual codes. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Not sure, but try to use swift `Array` instead of `NSArray`. Or try to mock your array with predefined values.